# Why does VisualVm does not show all threads in a running tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, profiler, visualvm

My tomcat (version: 5.5.25) runs an application which I try to profile with [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) (ver: 1.3.2). 
Everything looks nice but not all classes and methods are shown in visualVM. They ones that are missing run in thread [main]. I know this because this is the thread's name I receive if I a breakpoint has been hit. Classes which run outside main e.g. [worker1] , [worker2], ... are shown correctly.

Any idea what the reasons might be? Or what I could try?

Since the application I run (it is called [Assentis Docbase](http://www.assentis.com/products-en/docbase-en.html)) is closed-source they might have customized the default tomcat configuration. But they allowed me to extend the framework with my own classes and that are the ones I want to profile.

VisualVM I run with the default configuration as downloaded.

Comment: Are you certain they haven't renamed the main thread?

Comment: I am a little bit new to profiling tomcat. How to I check it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably need to customize profiling root methods. See [Profiling With VisualVM, Part 1](http://blogs.oracle.com/nbprofiler/entry/profiling_with_visualvm_part_1) and [Profiling With VisualVM, Part 2](http://blogs.oracle.com/nbprofiler/entry/profiling_with_visualvm_part_2). You can also use 'Sampler' tab to get high-level picture of what is your Tomcat doing.

Comment: Thats it! if you set root method on a high level you need to add two * (stars) after the dot. e.g. "mypackage.**"

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of reasons why you may not be able to see the "main" thread:

- The thread could have exited.
- The thread could have changed its name by calling `Thread.setName()`.

If you want to figure out the real reason, you will probably need to look at the Tomcat source code.

---

[This page](http://www.myeclipseide.com/documentation/quickstarts/profiler/#web) tells you where the settings are.  Google is your friend.

Comment: But if I start profiling before I call the method and stop after method has been called, than the main thread should have been called and must result in an entry in profiler? Doesn't it?

Comment: It seems that there is a setting called "Limit number of profiled threads". So my main thread is not profiled because it is e.g. thread number 33. But I do know how/where to set it. Any ideas?

Comment: @Stephen I alreday found the same link, but it only describe how you can use the settings if you use the eclipse-plugin of visualVM.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why VisualVM did not show my method calls in thread [main] is that VisualVM allows only to profile up to 32 threads simoultanously. It is NOT possible to allow more threads to be watched. This has been documented in [Profiling With VisualVM, Part 2](http://blogs.oracle.com/nbprofiler/entry/profiling_with_visualvm_part_2), section "Comparison With The NetBeans Profiler" they say:

"Profiled threads limit is always 32."

:-(

Comment: I don't think that this is valid in your case. Did you set the root methods?

Comment: I added to "Start profiling from classes" with the top-level package name where my method lives in. But it is not called. I think that the thread limit really is the reason because Aseentis Docbase creates a lot of new threads. They are needed because it is used for batch processing large files for outputmanagement.

Comment: Now I got it with the root methods. It is "mypackage.**" I forget one *. So "mypackage.*" is not working. I am happy now!

Comment: Ok, I am glad it works for you. Yes, "mypackage." does not work. There is a tooltip in the "Start profiling from classes" text area, which tells you correct syntax. Also the http://blogs.oracle.com/nbprofiler/entry/profiling_with_visualvm_part_2 post mentions the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You've probably badly configured "Start profiling from classes" in the plugin config.

Say you've configured `org.acme.competition.*` (A) for profiling:

[image: VisualVM Startup config dialog]

but you've accidentally profiled the class `org.acme.reference.ReferenceImpl` (B) using a command lie this:

```
$ cat source.txt | java -Xverify:none \
    -agentpath:/usr/share/visualvm/profiler/lib/deployed/jdk16/linux-amd64/libprofilerinterface.so=/usr/share/visualvm/profiler/lib,5140 \
    -cp bin/ org.acme.reference.ReferenceImpl
```

then this would be the wrong result:

[image: Wrong result]

When configuring VisualVM's Startup plugin config "Start profiling from classes" with `org.acme.reference.*` instead, the result is correct:

[image: Correct result]

See the [Startup profiler guide](https://visualvm.github.io/startupprofiler.html) too.